# non-comprehensible modulo calculation

Tags: r, modulo

I've got a strange result for my modulo query here. Maybe somebody has a solution for it:

```
d  <- seq(0.0,1.0,0.1)
lab.y <- ifelse(((d*10) %% 2.0 == 0.0),d, NA)
```

will give the result:

```
 [1] 0.0  NA 0.2  NA 0.4  NA  NA  NA 0.8  NA 1.0
```

so the `0.6` is missing.

I tried to add a query like:

```
ifelse((d*10/2 == 3.0), d, NA)
```

which is all `FALSE` even though

```
d*10/2
[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0
```

...
I don't really understand what's going on here.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Consider rounding for the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to floating point errors, you should look for low absolute differences instead of exact matches. It is not 0.6, but (just an example) 0.6000000003 or 0.5999999997. Try something like:

```
ifelse((abs((d*10) %% 2)<0.000001), d, NA)
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot!